# One to many relation throw exception on save

Tags: symfony

I have two entites. "Institution" and "User". The Insitution have a onetomany relation to user. I create a form "InstitutionType" and if i want to save a new insitution the "handleReqeust($request)" throw this exception.

```
Neither the property "users" nor one of the methods "addUser()"/"removeUser()", "setUsers()", "users()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "App\UserBundle\Entity\Institution".
```

**Entity User**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Institution", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="institution_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $institution;

public function setInstitution(\App\UserBundle\Entity\Institution $institution = null)
{
    $this->institution = $institution;

    return $this;
}

public function getInstitution()
{
    return $this->institution;
}
```

**Entity Institution**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="institution")
     */
    protected $users;

    public function addUser(\App\UserBundle\Entity\User $users)
    {
        $this->users[] = $users;

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeUser(\Ebm\UserBundle\Entity\User $users)
    {
        $this->users->removeElement($users);
    }

    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }
```

**InstitutionType**

```
$users = $this->entityManager->getRepository('AppUserBundle:User')->findByIsActive(true);

 ->add('users', 'entity', array(
                    'label'  => 'responsibleperson',
                    'attr' => array(),
                    'class' => 'AppUserBundle:User',
                    'choices' => $users,
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'expanded' => false,
                    'empty_value' => '----------------')
                )
```

Can someone help my to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Rename `addUser` to `addUsers`  and `removeUser` to `removeUsers`.

Symfony2/Doctrine obviously has no knowledge of singular/plural words and can't guess that to add a single entry to the `users` collection it would be semantically more correct to call `addUser()` instead of `addUsers`.

Please note that you can always use the console command `doctrine:generate:entities AcmeDemoBundle:Institution` to generate missing fields in the entity classes.

If this doesn't help you need to make sure you use the same notation in your form type like in your entity configuration (annotation, yml or xml).

Comment: i generate the setters and getters with doctrine:generate:entities AcmeDemoBundle:Institution but this not solve my issue. This generates always "addUser". If i modify this to "addUsers" , then the same error is appear